# regex for slug and id

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm tying to create a regex for matching part of a url which contains a slug followed by a dash followed by an ID.

**example-slug-ID0001**

Matching the whole string I've got with `([A-Za-z0-1\-]+)`

I'd like to match the slug and ID in two groups but I'm unsure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: your first problem is that your question suggests you have a slug followed by a dash, but your example has two dashes.

Comment: have you tested your regex using some sort of tool (https://www.regexpal.com/, for example) to see what your regex actually does?

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. The slug is example-slug which contains a dash and is followed by another dash and ID.

I think I have something which might work `([-\w]+)-([\w]+)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're looking for this, which matches "one or more alphanumeric + dash sequences (the slug) followed by an ID":

`((?:\w+-)+)(.*)`

edit: if you don't wish to match such strings such as "example-slug" by itself (per Claies' comment) use: `((?:\w+-)+)ID\d+`

https://regex101.com/r/sqP6mO/1/

Comment: but wouldn't this match `example-slug` (which doesn't have an ID portion)?  seems like this has the same issue as the option that was in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting by dash and getting the last item should be enough:

```js
s = 'example-slug-ID0001'

console.log( s.split('-')[2] )

console.log( /[^-]+$/.exec(s)[0] )

console.log( s.match(/[^-]+/g)[2] )

console.log( s.replace(/.*-/, '') )

console.log( s.slice( s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your regex, your id should contains only the digits 0 and 1.

To get the slug and the id in 2 separate groups, you might use:

[`([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)-(ID[01]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EexogB/1)

**Explanation**

- The first capturing group `(`

  - Match a character or digit one or more times `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
  - A non capturing group `(?:`
  - Match a hyphen and a character or digit one or more times `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
  - Close non capturing group `)*` and repeat that zero or more times
- Close first capturing group `)`
- Second capturing group `(`

  - Match ID and one or more digits `ID\d+`
- Close second capturing group `)`

If your id can contain digits from 0-9, you could use change `[01]` to `\d+`.

If your slug can contain only characters, you could change `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[a-zA-Z]`, or when you use the case insensitive flag, you could use `[a-z]` or `[a-z\d]`

Also allowing underscores, you might use:

[`([\w]+(?:-[\w]+)*)-(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/6Vruo5/1/)